# KotlinDslScriptsParameter(correlationId=782785944245786, scriptFiles=[]) with Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

With Android Studio 4.0 I'm seeing the following line printed in the build output when syncing the project with Gradle files:

```
KotlinDslScriptsParameter(correlationId=782841456084562, scriptFiles=[]) => StandardKotlinDslScriptsModel(scripts=[], commonModel=CommonKotlinDslScriptModel(classPath=[], sourcePath=[], implicitImports=[]), dehydratedScriptModels={}) - took 0.0 secs
```

I'm assuming this is some kind of debug leftover in the Android Gradle plugin. Is there any way to suppress it?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I am also seeing when updating my android studio

Comment: I get the same extra message. According to [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-35552), it will be fixed in Gradle 6.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a minor bug in Gradle <6.2, not directly related to Android Studio or the Android Gradle plugin: A `println` call caused excessive logging, and was fixed in https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11730

With the PR merged, the debug output can no longer be seen by default. So the solution is to [update Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:upgrading_wrapper) to 6.2 or later (which will most likely be included by default with an upcoming version of the Android Gradle plugin).

To test and recreate the previous behavior with **Gradle 6.2+**, set the `org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.logging` system property to `true`, e.g. in `gradle.properties`:

```
systemProp.org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.logging.tapi=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update Gradle to 6.2

In `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip
```

**Paste this code in your gradle-wrapper.properties of your app module**